# Why my scss doesn't take the universal selector?

Tags: css, sass

I'm learning Sass and I choose to try with Scss syntax, but there is an error when I try to complile the scss code to css.

Here is the command line's error:

```
> starter@1.0.0 compile:sass C:\Users\xxx
> node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css

{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/Users/xxx/sass/main.scss",
  "line": 14,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "Invalid CSS after \"*\": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was \",\"",
  "formatted": "Error: Invalid CSS after \"*\": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was \",\"\n        
  on line 14 of sass/main.scss\n>> *,\r\n   ^\n"
}
```

This is my Scss file:

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit; 
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body{
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1,7;
    color: #777;
    padding: 3rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And I'm running it through the Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  }
}
```

For some reason it says that the universal selector is not Css code, and I tried by comenting that selector out but then it says the same for the html selector.

-------UPDATE-------
The error stopped once I used the 7-1 css architecture. The universal selector became acepted when I put it in another file, so the problem was fixed but I don't know why.

Comment: You left __*__ after the closing tag of the all selector, try deleting it

Comment: I edited the question, that was a typo but the main problem is the * first universal selector, it says it's not a valid css and I don't nkow why

Comment: Did you try to delete the universal selector and try run it again? Does it run without errors?